# How Kotlin coroutines will use Project Loom?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, kotlin-coroutines, green-threads

Right now, Kotlin coroutines are implemented without help of JVM. It does not use something like green (virtual) threads. You can read about implementation of coroutines here - https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#implementation-details

In the near future (like, 1-2 year), project Loom (implementation of green threads in JVM) will be released. You can read details about it here - [http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html)

So, will Kotlin use these virtual threads as compilation backend? Or there are some reasons, why it is not possible? I talk about JVM target with needed version (it is obvious, that we need own implementation for android).

Actually, there is more general question. Do we really need Kotlin coroutines, when Project Loom will be released?

Comment: There's a lot to read on kotlin forum if you want more information : [Search loom on Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/search?q=loom). There are many aspects to consider, and performance is only one of them. Another is how easy the API is to understand / use. One other is about control. Do you (as developer/language user) have full control of the async model or not ? Many questions difficult to answer until  stable loom version is released.

Comment: Coroutines are more than lightweight threads, they are not only used for multi-threading. Coroutines implementation can be used in place of deep recursion as storing stack in heap, suspend-await (at particular timing) as coroutine are by itself nothing but uses thread to get execute but are not thread by themselves. And are flexible, implementing structured concurrency it provides cancellations and more... If project Loom have better optimized threading support, coroutines-library may use them to dispatch coroutines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Roman Elizarov [outlined in his talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FF19HJDqMo&ab_channel=JetBrainsTV) there will be *interoperation* with Project Loom.

As for the need for coroutines, you have to realize that Kotlin is a multiplatform language which means that coroutines have to work on all platforms, including the browser and native code.

Even if they will use Project Loom on the JVM the API has to stay consistent, since the same code will be compiled to all platforms.